# Force all screens to same display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I want to create a configuration (a service running in the background is also okay) to automatically force any future monitor attached to the PC to

(1) mirror the primary monitor,

(2) use the same resolution 1920x1080 @60fps.

Any suggestions? Note that, this should be automatic and I don't know what monitors are connected to which ports in advance.

OS: Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.5

Comment: What GPU installed on your pc? Because it differs

Comment: I have an internal Intel GPU and an Nivida GPU on PCI.